# mdadm: can't remove components in RAID 1

Tags: centos, raid, mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I have my /boot partition in a RAID 1 array using mdadm.  This array has degraded a few times in the past, and every time I remove the physical drive, add a new one, bring the array being to normal, it uses a new drive letter.  Leaving the old one still in the array and failed.  I can't seem to remove those all components that no longer exist.

```
[root@xxx ~]# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdg1[10] sde1[8](F) sdb1[7](F) sdd1[6](F) sda1[4] sdc1[5]
      358336 blocks super 1.0 [4/3] [UUU_]
```

Here's what I've tried to remove the non-existent drives and partitions.  For example, `/dev/sdb1`.

```
[root@xxx ~]# mdadm /dev/md0 -r /dev/sdb1
mdadm: Cannot find /dev/sdb1: No such file or directory
[root@xxx ~]# mdadm /dev/md0 -r faulty
mdadm: Cannot find 8:49: No such file or directory
[root@xxx ~]# mdadm /dev/md0 -r detached
mdadm: Cannot find 8:49: No such file or directory
```

That `8:49` I believe refers to the major and minor number shown in `--detail`, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.  I'm trying to avoid a reboot or restarting mdadm.

```
[root@xxx ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md0 
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.0
  Creation Time : Thu Aug  8 18:07:35 2013
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 358336 (350.00 MiB 366.94 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 358336 (350.00 MiB 366.94 MB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 6
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sat Apr 18 16:44:20 2015
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 3
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : xxx.xxxxx.xxx:0  (local to host xxx.xxxxx.xxx)
           UUID : 991eecd2:5662b800:34ba96a4:2039d40a
         Events : 694

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       4       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
      10       8       97        1      active sync   /dev/sdg1
       5       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       6       0        0        6      removed

       6       8       49        -      faulty
       7       8       17        -      faulty
       8       8       65        -      faulty
```

**Note:** The array is legitimately degraded right now and I'm getting a new drive in there as we speak.  However, as you can see above, that shouldn't matter.  I should still be able to remove `/dev/sdb1` from this array.

Comment: You don't need a --force to remove a disk in the "removed" state, and it might hide a more serious problem. Leave it off.

Answer (score 18):

It's because the device nodes no longer exist on your system (probably udev removed them when the drive died). You should be able to remove them by using the keyword `failed` or `detached` instead:

```
mdadm -r /dev/md0 failed     # all failed devices
mdadm -r /dev/md0 detached   # failed ones that aren't in /dev anymore
```

If your version of mdadm is too old to do that, you might be able to get it to work by `mknod`'ing the device to exist again. Or, honestly, just ignore it—it's not really a problem, and should go away the next time you reboot.

Comment: I've tried using the keywords, you can see the output it gave me in the original post.  I'll take a look at `mknod`.  Yeah, it's probably not an issue, but I'm OCD, lol.

Comment: Yep, I used mknod to get this done and it worked.

Comment: @SajanParikh indeed, somehow I'd missed the lines showing you'd already tried failed and detached. Glad that mknod worked.

Comment: Clarifying note: The OP did not state he used "failed". I got the same errors they did, but "failed" worked for me. They used "faulty".

Answer (score 7):

What I ended up doing was using `mknod` like @derobert suggested to create the devices that `mdadm` was looking for.  I tried the major/minor numbers mdadm was telling me it couldn't find with the different drive letters I was trying to remove until it worked.

```
mknod /dev/sde1 b 8 17
```

Then I had to use the `--force` option to get it remove the component.

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --remove --force /dev/sde1
```

Then, I removed that created block device.

```
rm /dev/sde1
```

Comment: Hmm... 8:17 is sdb1. (8:65 is sde1) But that one was missing too, so I guess that works...

Comment: This didn't worked for me, `mdadm` continued to say: "device or resource busy", but this made me try to feed him not with a fake block device, but with a "true" block device such as a loopback mounted image. At this point, I discovered that I had a stale `/dev/loop` that was still using a file on the degraded array. I detached it and finally `mdadm` let me stop the array. Horay! For everybody reading this, there is always a logical explanation for `mdadm` being so jerk, so look for a stale process/file/mountpoint/nfs handler/open bash/loopback device/etc. still using the degraded array. :)

Comment: I was able to use exactly the same major and minor versions (8:18 in my case) to mknod a fake /dev/sdb2 device. After that, mdadm --remove deleted stale record of /dev/sdb2 from /proc/mdstat. Remember to rm /dev/sdb2 after successful --remove action.

Answer (score 6):

You could also fix just by degreasing number of disks in array:

In my case I have raid-1 array `/dev/md0` with `/dev/sda1` and "removed". I just simply shrunk it to use one drive only:

```
mdadm -G /dev/md0 --raid-devices=1 --force
```

After that removed was really removed (no removed lines anymore in `mdadm --detail`)

Comment: You have to be careful with this approach, though. Understand well what type of RAID you're dealing with before modifying --raid-devices.

Comment: This is exactly __how to remove failed drive__.